# Getting error on publishing mvc app to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, publish

I have published web site on Azure, but it's showing page with this message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

I don't how to troubleshot this.

I just added

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> under  <system.webServer>
```

and now its showing blank page.

Comment: try checking out your error in console of browser, we can't just help you out with the data you provided..

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to diagnose this would be to use Azure's Visual Studio Online service to amend the config file, setting the custom errors option to off. Then you will get a detailed error message.

You can turn this on under the configure tab of your website, look for this:

[image: Edit in VS Online option in Azure Portal]

Then jump over to the dashboard and look for this:

[image: Link on Dashboard]

Finally, open web.config and set **customErrors** to off, like so:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Comment: I set it off but still the same message